# How to remove an item in an Array if deselecting it in tableView swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

that if I deselect an item in tableView it didn't get deletet from the Array. When I select an item it works fine but if I want to deselect I don't know how to code it. My Question is how I can delete this item from the Array.
Here is the tableView code:

```
var highlightsArray: [String] = []
    
    var highlightRow: String = ""

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return highlightsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "com.nils.PrototypeCellHighlights", for: indexPath) as? CheckableTableViewCell
        let highlights = highlightsArray[indexPath.row].components(separatedBy: ", " )
        cell?.textLabel?.text = highlights.first
        
        return cell!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
              
                 if tableView == highlightTableView {
                     highlightRow = highlightsArray[indexPath.row]
                     let selected_indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
                     for indexPath in selected_indexPaths! {
                         let highlightName = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                        let highlightText = (highlightName?.textLabel?.text)!
                        if highlightValue.contains(highlightText) {
                            
                        }
                        else {
                           highlightValue.append((highlightName?.textLabel?.text)!)
                        }
                        
                      
                  }
               }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
             
       
    }
```

Additionally I have a class for the tableView Cell:

```
class CheckableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
       
    }
}
```

At least here is the finish Button:

```
   @objc func doneButton() {
        
    
        if highlightValue == [] {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You didn't select anything", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                  
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        
        print(highlightValue)
        highlightValue = []
    }
```

If you have any questions please let me know

Comment: you need to set up a data structure to store the values of checkmark ..and then later go through that structure and find which are unchecked and delete those elements

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove an item from the array when you deselect the row?
Try,

```
didDeselectRowAt{
  highlightValue.remove(at:indexpath.row)
  table.reloadData()
}
```